# toString() representation output

Tags: java, tostring

I have a bug in the code and believe me I've run debugging many times to find what's wrong with code but cannot understand what is wrong. I have to output the contents of 2d Arraylist. For example, if I do:

```
Board<String> board = new Board<String>(-4,1,-2,3,"A"); 
System.out.println(board);
```

it outputs me the following:

```
   | -2| -1|  0|  1|  2|  3|
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+
-4 |  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+
-3 |  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+
-2 |  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+
-1 |  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+
 0 |  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+
 1 |  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

But when I change the fourth value, `3`, to higher number, for example, `4` (`(-4,1,-2,4,"A")`), then it says:

```
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 6
```

All of my constructors work well, and I assume the bug is in the `toString()` method. And again, I've tried to debug it several times but still cannot make my mind what can be wrong here. Could smb please help me? The error happens in this line inside `toString()` method:

Comment: `for(int i = minRow; i <= maxRow; i++){` loops suspicious, but consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @Andreas The fact that the error occurs in the toString method does not mean that the bug is also in toString method.

Comment: Could you post the complete stacktrace of the exception so that we could find the exact location of the problem

Comment: I think the error is in one of the get methods. Extract myBoard.get(row++) in a variable, so you know wether its the first or the second method. And please post your get-method implementations

Comment: Where did I even use get() method ? @Typischserg

Comment: You said the error is here: secondLine1 += "|  " + myBoard.get(row++).get(col++);

Comment: get() is a built-in Arraylist method! @Typischserg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You increase the row for each column:

```
for(int j = minCol; j <= maxCol; j++){
    secondLine1 += "|  " + myBoard.get(row++).get(col++);
    secondLine2 += "+---";
}
```

This is also the reason why it works for #rows >= #columns but not for #rows < #columns

Extract myBoard.get(row++) as variable before inner for loop, like

```
 ArrayList<T> rowCells = myBoard.get(row++);
 for(int j = minCol; j <= maxCol; j++){
       secondLine1 += "|  " + rowCells.get(col++);
       secondLine2 += "+---";
 }
```

and move

```
row = 0;
```

out of the outer loop.

Or, here is a suggestion with the whole class (please pay attention, I only improved the indexed access. There is enough room for further improvements, e.g string concatenations):

```
public class Board<T> {
private T element;
private int minCol;
private int maxCol;
private int minRow;
private int maxRow;
private int rowCount;
private int colCount;
private List<List<T>> myBoard;

public Board(int minRow, int maxRow, int minCol, int maxCol, T fillElem) {
    this.minRow = minRow;
    this.maxRow = maxRow;
    this.minCol = minCol;
    this.maxCol = maxCol;
    this.rowCount = maxRow - minRow + 1;
    this.colCount = maxCol - minCol + 1;

    if (fillElem == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot set elements to null");
    } else {
        this.element = fillElem;
    }

    myBoard = new ArrayList<List<T>>(rowCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        List<T> rowLine = new ArrayList<T>(colCount);
        myBoard.add(rowLine);
        for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
            rowLine.add(element);
    }
}

private T getCellValueAt(int row, int column) {
    return myBoard.get(row - minRow).get(column - minCol);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String result = "";
    if (this.element instanceof String) {
        String elem = (String) this.element;
        String firstLine1 = "   ";
        String firstLine2 = "   ";
        String first1 = "";
        String first2 = "";
        String secondLine1 = "";
        String secondLine2 = "   ";

        switch (elem.length()) {
        case 1:
            result = "";
            // Contructs the first two lines!
            firstLine1 = "   ";
            firstLine2 = "   ";
            first1 = "";
            first2 = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
                if (i >= 0) {
                    first1 += "|  " + i;
                } else {
                    first1 += "| " + i;
                }
                first2 += "+---";
            }
            firstLine1 += first1 + "|\n";
            firstLine2 += first2 + "+\n";

            // Constrcuts the rest!
            secondLine1 = "";
            secondLine2 = "   ";

            for (int row = minRow; row <= maxRow; row++) {
                if (row >= 0) {
                    secondLine1 += " " + row + " ";
                } else {
                    secondLine1 += row + " ";
                }

                for (int column = minCol; column <= maxCol; column++) {
                    secondLine1 += "|  " + getCellValueAt(row, column);
                    secondLine2 += "+---";
                }
                secondLine1 += "|\n";
                secondLine1 += secondLine2 + "+\n";
                secondLine2 = "   ";

                // secondLine2 += "+\n   ";
            }

            result += firstLine1 + firstLine2 + secondLine1; // + secondLine2;
            break;
        }
        return builder.append(result).toString();
    }
    return "";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Board<String> board = new Board<String>(-4, 1, -2, 4, "A");
    System.out.println(board);
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by extracting myBiard.get (row++) ?

Comment: I just added a full solution, that I have tested for your two cases

Comment: Thank you so much! @Typischserg. I still have to fix some other bugs with the regard to the signs in front of minRow, maxCol.., but thanks! I guess my problem was in accessing the values at [row][col] position, right??

Comment: You are welcome. Yes and no, the access occurred at [row][column] showed the problem, but the actual mistake was to increase row (row++) in the loop of columns(  for(int j = minCol; j <= maxCol; j++){ ) so it was always: row == column true. So you actually has printed the diagonal, not each row. If you had different values on your board you have seen the wrong output

Comment: Tip: to avoid similar mistakes, avoid long and complex methods. Encapsulate all relevant parts in methods. As as you see in my solution, use separate methods to access data in [row][column] or create methods to print one row or to print the header, etc. Try to separate operations in methods with good names and single responsibilities. -> Clean Code. That can help you a lot to find such errors